# What are the default values for StreamReader?

Tags: c#, default, streamreader

I need to use this constructor `public StreamReader(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, int bufferSize, bool leaveOpen)` in order to set `leaveOpen` to `true`. And in order to do that I need to set the other parameters as well (`Encoding encoding, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, int bufferSize`). I want to use `StreamReader` as it is so I do not want to give some random values. What are the default values for these parameters?

By the way, I know that I can use `StreamReader` without `using`. And GC will get rid of it without touching the stream.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The default values are the following:

- Encoding: Encoding.UTF8
- detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true
- DefaultBufferSize: 1024

You can see the constructors and the values yourself by visiting [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,6875bce072fdba23)

Answer (score 5):

You can inspect [the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,b5fe1efcec14de32) to determine this.

It reveals that:

- detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks is true
- DefaultBufferSize is 1024 or 4096
- encoding is Encoding.UTF8
- leaveOpen is false

Personally, I'd make the DefaultBufferSize 4096 for a desktop app.

Answer (score 3):

`Encoding.UTF8`, `true`, and `1024`, respectively.

Source: [the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs.html#fb4c1bb0600a65dd).

That the default for `Encoding` is `Encoding.UTF8` and the default for `bufferSize` is 1024 is also [documented in the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yhfzs7at), but the default for `detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks` doesn't appear to be.

Answer (score 0):

`Stream stream` you need to pass to read from. `Encoding encoding` default AFAIK is `UTF-8`. `int bufferSize` is minimum 128 characters. `bool leaveOpen` is `false` by default and so it will call `Dispose()` after reading the stream

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952(v=vs.110).aspx) said it clearly.