# Is there a benefit in closing StreamReader (or StreamWriter) when I close Stream explicitly?

Tags: c#, stream, streamreader, idisposable

I have the following code. In here I am using the `StreamReader` constructor with `leaveOpen: true` and in order to do that I need to give the previous parameters which [I manage to get their default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584527/what-are-the-default-values-for-streamreader). This is cumbersome. Since I use `stream` with `using` do I gain anything for using the `StreamReader` with `using`? Does answer change if it is a `StreamWriter` instead?

```
using (Strem stream = ...)
{
    ...
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

What if any do I lose if use the following code instead?

```
using (Strem stream = ...)
{
    ...
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);

    ...

    ...
}
```

Comment: It gets closed after the using statement finishes. No need to explicitly close. A try/finally is complied which calls close to both.

Comment: @Botonomous What I am trying to ask is what happens if I do not use the inner using

Comment: Try it and find out. I would imagine the GC would pick it up after stream falls out of scope. For best practices, you should leave it in.

Comment: @Botonomous I do not like the necessity of using the default values for other parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need to close a `StreamWriter` (generally via the `using` block), or else data in its buffer could be lost.

Because both `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` default to closing the stream automatically, if you want to eliminate one `using` block from your code, it should be the `Stream` that you remove from `using`.

If you can't do that, for example you've borrowed the `Stream` from elsewhere that doesn't want you to close it, then you must use the `leaveOpen` parameter you're already aware of.  The reason that you can't just omit the `using` statement for a `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` in order to leave it open, is that the garbage collector will still trigger some cleanup (although not as much) since the object is unreachable... only this will now occur at an unrelated time, creating an unpredictable bug that's very hard to find.

It is indeed ugly that you can't specify `leaveOpen` without explicitly controlling the buffer size, etc.  May I suggest a helper method along the lines of `StreamReader CreateStreamReaderLeaveOpen(Stream)`?

Answer (score 3):

Because you have `leaveOpen` set to `true` in the constructor disposing of a `StreamReader` [does nothing execpt call the the `Dispose` method of the `TextReader` class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,011147a163b10458), which itself does nothing at all.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    // Dispose of our resources if this StreamReader is closable.
    // Note that Console.In should be left open.
    try {
        // Note that Stream.Close() can potentially throw here. So we need to 
        // ensure cleaning up internal resources, inside the finally block.  
        if (!LeaveOpen && disposing && (stream != null))
            stream.Close();
    }
    finally {
        if (!LeaveOpen && (stream != null)) {
            stream = null;
            encoding = null;
            decoder = null;
            byteBuffer = null;
            charBuffer = null;
            charPos = 0;
            charLen = 0;
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

With a `StreamWriter` it does change a bit because [it will not flush it's internal buffers to the underlying stream unless you dispose of the writer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,f922405b11eca536).

Comment: The question asked about `StreamWriter` as well, which has much more complex conditions for performing operations (including Flush on the stream) at the time of `Dispose()`.

Comment: Is there a benefit to using LeaveOpen? I saw some example code set this bit true inside a while loop created streamReader.